# How to have database (mysql) snapshot for each bug submited

Tags: mysql, database, debugging, testing

I am trying to find a way/tool to be able to do the following:

- testers are testing the application on the main testing environment and find a bug.
- They would **generate a snapshot** of the db used and attach it to the bug
- Developer when working on the bug would be able to load this snapshot somewhere on the development server and used the instance created to work on this bug
- Once the bug is fixed (and tested successfully) the instance created on the server would be destroyed.

The only thing I could think of is using Virtual Machine. Each developers would have a VM instance on the dev server and would be able to load snapshots of the bug they are working on in it. But this mean taking a snapshot of the whole environment (which is big).
 More over the testing are done on the dev server which is a replica of live. So nothing is changing except the db/middleware and front end.
I would love to be able to find a tool that would permit to just create/load snapshot of db (and even maybe middleware) and lets devs (so per dev instance) choosing which snapshot they want to work with.

Do you have any ideas of such tools or ways to do so?
I've tried to look around but haven't found anything helpful really.

Comment: I have the same kind of question... I have a testing environment, with a database, where I want testers to take a snapshot of the MySql database through a kind of webinterface before they start testing a functionality. If they encounter a problem, they can file a bug with the snapshot of the database, so developers can simulate the problem. On the other hand, when no problems occur, testers should be able to reset the database to a certain snapshot, so they can test another part of the application with the same initial data. Did you find anything useful or does some has an answer already?

Comment: Nope I haven't found anything yet :/